# ggplot2: scale_y_reverse() for only one group of facet grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Here's an example using builtin R data:

```
data(mpg, package = "ggplot2")  # load data
g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) + geom_point()
     + labs(title = "hwy vs displ", caption = "Source: mpg")
     + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)
g2 <- g + facet_grid(cyl ~ class)
g2
```

Which produces this plot:
[image: reproducible plot resulting from code block]

Is there a way to, say, scale_y_reverse() for just the 8 cylinder group?

Comment: Not really. Maybe if you do `scales = 'free_y'`, though I still doubt it'd be simple.

Comment: The ggplot philosophy would consider that to be a misleading visualization, since facets are designed such that values can be compared across groups. It would be better to generate separate plots and if you must combine, to use something like `gridExtra::grid.arrange`.

Comment: in my real example, i have 3 groups horizontally x 2 groups vertically, and for the purpose of visualization, i would like to reverse the y-axis on the lower group. my current solution is to multiply the values by -1 and use scales = 'free_y' but this is annoying in trying to e.g. map text, annotate, etc.